# Convert XML Time Date Type with timezone information to local time

Tags: xml, datetime, time, timezone

I'm writing a function to convert a XML field of the XML Time data type and I run into the following (practical) problem:

How do you actually convert a XML Time date type to local time when there is timezone information added ex.

```
<MyTime>14:16:20+02:00</MyTime>
```

It's not as simple as just convert it to UTC time (12:16:20) and convert that back to your local time, due to stuff like Daylightsavings/summetime.
If you have the date part it isn't a problem as you also have the date on which to convert back to UTC and then to the local time of that date. But due to Daylightsavings/summertime the **+02:00** might also depend on WHEN the time was written and ofcourse location.
For instance in the Netherlands if I would use such an application, which adds timezone info to the Time data type, to write it during the summer it would have **14:16:20+02:00** but in the winter it would be **14:16:20+01:00**.

So without knowing when it was written I would get the following when reading back the XML on a specific date from a specific location:

```
Location           = The Netherlands
Date of converting = 10 august 2021 (summertime, +02:00)

'14:16:20'        =>  14:16:20 (as there is no timezone)
'14:16:20+02:00'  =>  14:16:20 (if using date) 
'14:16:20+01:00'  =>  15:16:20 (if using date)

Date of converting = 10 januari 2021 (wintertime, +01:00)

'14:16:20'        =>  14:16:20 (as there is no timezone)
'14:16:20+02:00'  =>  13:16:20 (if using date) 
'14:16:20+01:00'  =>  14:16:20 (if using date)
```

I could not find in the W3C specs how to deal with it, like always using a fictitious date like 1-1-1970 to convert to/from UTC.

I'll probably gonna just ignore timezone information unless it's **Z** or **+00:00**, or if a testdate has been passed to the function. But maybe there is a default way of handling this, which I just missed in the original W3C specs.

Comment: if a UTC offset like `+02:00` is (assuming correctly) specified, you can always convert to UTC. This is not a time zone information in a geographical sense. The problem arises if you want to convert from UTC time to local time without knowing the date. Can you make the date a requirement, to avoid such ambiguities?

Comment: @MrFuppes But that's the whole problem haha, only having a time not a date, and the time having timezone information. So that's what my question is about, how do you handle such a situation, as the official specifications don't seem to touch this problem. I would have thought there might be something standard like, when only having time, you convert from local time to UTC always on a specific date like 1-1-1970 (as an example as linux timestamp has it as it's startdate).
I can't do anything about it as I'm only reading in XML's from other sources.

Comment: You could also use the current date or try to best-guess it from the context, but I don't think there is a "best practice". It's a gamble if you absolutely can't leave it as UTC.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said much about your technology constraints, but in XPath 3.1 you can use `format-dateTime($value, '[H01]:[M01]:[S01][Z01:01]', (), (), 'Europe/Amsterdam')`.

(Implementations may differ in what timezone names they recognise).

Comment: I purposely didn't say which technology I was using, as it is a general question on how to deal with such a situation: only having time, with timezone information. That isn't bound by any technology constrains. So it's all about not knowing WHEN (date) the timezone information was written, so no way of actually getting the correct time back as daylightsavings or summertime is not know, but makes a big difference on when it was written and when it is converted back. Or my thinking is flawed, haha, which is also very possible.

Comment: The information is out there in the timezone databases, but the way you get access to the information is very dependent on the libraries available in your chosen processing environment. But perhaps I misunderstood the question: if you have a time and a timezone but no date, then it's obviously impossible to know if it's in summer time, even if you know the place.